# UFT 11.53 Flex Dialog Issue

Tags: hp-uft

UFT 11.53 is not recognizing flex dialog.

I have a scenario where I have set a value in Flex edit and the hierarichy is Browser().Page().FlexWindow().FlexDialog().FlexEdit().Set "Value" and i have a function regFXsetValue() to do this.

When I am executing this function individually UFT 11.53 is setting value, but when I run that particular function along with other functions in the script UFT 11.53 is not identifying the flex dialog. It is stopping our batch execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that some other function which is getting called before this function is affecting the object recognition of the Flex edit object. Best is to put UFT in debug mode. Go through each line and just before this function to set value in flex edit is called, hold the execution and spy this object. Check identification properties and see if they are same as the ones you have used in your OR or in descriptive programming. I am sure you will find the bug.

Comment: Hi Sir,  Thanks for your reply.  Okay I will check in this way and let you know.  But, Yesterday I kept break point that function and executed the script.  In this way it is setting the value.  Let me explain clearly pPreConditionEquipmentCreation under this pSelectorCreateEqipmentsInLISMasters, so when I apply breakpoint at this level and run the script it is setting value.  When I remove breakpoint, it is not setting the value.  it say Flex Dialog is not identified.

Comment: Hi Sir, as you said, I have tried debug mode also, but as I said if I am using breaking points, then it is setting the value.  It is identifying the Flex Dialog.    When I run without breakpoints, script is failing.

Comment: Can you try giving some wait before the script line which is setting the value. May be wait of 20-30 seconds.

Comment: @Vvvaib..thanx a ton sir, it is working.  I have used Browser().Refresh and then wait(20), now it is working.  I have may other scripts, I will check and let you know.